# Fatal Exception re WAS AdminClient

Tags: java, websphere, jmx

I'm attempting to monitor a Websphere 7 ennvironment using MBeans,  but running into numerous problems.  First,  I receive the following exception when using the code posted below:

> com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: Could not
>   create RMI Connector to connect to host localhost at port 2809

Here is the code generating the exception:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClient;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory;


public class JustAdminClient {
private AdminClient adminClient;

private void initialize() throws Exception {
    try {
        // Initialize the AdminClient.
        Properties adminProps = new Properties();
        adminProps.setProperty("type", AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_RMI);
        adminProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "false"); 
        adminProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "localhost");
        adminProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, "2809");
        adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(adminProps);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        throw ex;
    }
}   // end method

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JustAdminClient adClient = new JustAdminClient();
    try {
        adClient.initialize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   // end main

}   // end class
```

Second,  I'm running WAS standalone with security disabled.  Do I need to configure any self-signed certs?

My security.xml shows:

```xml
<security:Security xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
  xmlns:orb.securityprotocol="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/orb.securityprotocol.xmi"
  xmlns:security="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/security.xmi" xmi:id="Security_1"
  useLocalSecurityServer="true" useDomainQualifiedUserNames="false" 
  issuePermissionWarning="true" activeProtocol="BOTH" 
  enforceJava2Security="false" enforceFineGrainedJCASecurity="false"
  appEnabled="true" dynamicallyUpdateSSLConfig="true" 
  allowBasicAuth="true" activeAuthMechanism="LTPA_1"
  activeUserRegistry="LocalOSUserRegistry" enabled="false" cacheTimeout="600"
  defaultSSLSettings="SSLConfig_RXCW510MONNode01_1" adminPreferredAuthMech="RSAToken_1">
```

per the link:  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21295051

Note,  I can contact port 2809 two ways,  via WSadamin and a Java prog containing the following:

```
private void connect(String host,String port) throws Exception
    {
        String jndiPath="/WsnAdminNameService#JMXConnector";

        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:iiop://"+host+"/jndi/corbaname:iiop:"+host+":"+port+jndiPath);
        System.out.println("URL = " + url);
        //JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:iiop://192.168.0.175:9100/jndi/JMXConnector");

        Hashtable h = new Hashtable();

        //Specify the user ID and password for the server if security is enabled on server.

        //Establish the JMX connection.
        System.out.println("Before JMXConnector");
        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, h);

        //Get the MBean server connection instance.
        System.out.println("Before getMBeanServerConnection");
        mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

        System.out.println("Connected to Application Server");
    }   // end method
```

Any ideas?  I'm lost and apologize for the long thread,  but better to see the info upfront.

Comment: It seems like you have a few different questions here.  It would be best if you were to split this up into one question per ... question ... If you can make your question more concise, people will have an easier time helping you.

Comment: Basically,  what's the procedure to ensure I query the WAS using Admin MBean on a standalone WAS server?

Comment: I think I'm making progress, but not sure. I modified the initial code example to throw additional exceptions finding a missing jar file.  However,  now I’m encountering 
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: I’m new to JNDI.  My question,  do I need to add some values to an InitalContext object?  Also,  where do I find a list of the JNDI parms I need to pass WAS?  So far,  my searches I’m not finding the links or don’t understand the returned info?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my problem using the follwoing example code snippet and notations.  Note,  pay particular attention to thrown exception and messages re: mssing classes;  i.e. focusing on the message "could not create" message may mislead you

requires the following jar files:

- %WAS_HOME%\runtimes\com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_7.0.0.jar 
  %WAS_HOME%\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar 
  %WAS_HOME%\plugins\deploytool\itp\com.ibm.websphere.v7_7.0.0.v20080817\wasJars\com.ibm.ws.admin.core.jar
  %WAS_HOME%\runtimes\com.ibm.ws.admin.client_7.0.0.jar  requires
  CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP.  CONNECTOR_TYPE_RMI fails to connect;  maybe a jar issue based on the stack trace messages

public class JMXAdminClientSimple {

`private AdminClient adminClient;
    private ObjectName nodeagent = null;

```
public void initialize() throws Exception {
    try {
        // Initialize the AdminClient.
        Properties props = new Properties();
          props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "localhost");
          props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, "8880");
          props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
          props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "false");
          props.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, "");
          props.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, "");
          adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        throw ex;
    }
}`
```

Comment: They have DeveloperWorks article on this if you haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0):

To use the AdminClient API with security disabled on a Sun/Oracle JRE, you need the following JARs in the classpath:

- runtimes/com.ibm.ws.admin.client_7.0.0.jar
- runtimes/com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar
- runtimes/com.ibm.ws.orb_7.0.0.jar

With these JARs, RMI should also work.